# How to run a Perl command?

Tags: command-line, perl

If I am running the following command to replace a string `dst_` with `dst_addr_` in multiple files.

```
perl -pi -w -e ’s/dst_/dst_addr_/g;’ *.tcl
```

it shows the following error:

```
Unrecognized character \xE2; marked by <-- HERE after <-- HERE near column 1 at -e line 1.
’: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see how this is Ubuntu specific. This might be more appropriate on Superuser.com or Unix/Linux.

Comment: @gertvdijk sorry, my previous comment had a bad link. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/

Answer (score 4):

I think your issue is caused by the improper use of `’`.

You should use `'` ('s/dst_/dst_addr_/g;') in your command.

```
perl -pi -e 's/dst_/dst_addr_/g' *.tcl
```

should replace all the occurance of **dst_** with **dst_addr_** in all .tcl files.

Hope this helps